# What does "and" do in this function?

Tags: haskell

"sorted" is a function to check if a list in sorted in ascending order.

```
pairs :: [a] -> [(a,a)]
pairs xs = zip xs (tail xs)

sorted :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
sorted xs = and [x <= y | (x,y) <- pairs xs]
```

I am wondering what does "and" do in sorted xs?

Comment: `ands` all comparisons `x <= y` for all consecutive values, so it checks whether the list is sorted or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It calls the [`and` function from the standard library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:and):

> ```
> and :: Foldable t => t Bool -> Bool
> ```
>
> `and` returns the conjunction of a container of Bools. For the result to be `True`, the container must be finite; `False`, however, results from a `False` value finitely far from the left end.

Comment: I always found the `and` and `or` functions kind of unfortunately named. Usually, the formulation with `all` / `any` reads nicer, as in: `sorted = all (uncurry (<=)) . pairs`.

Answer (score 0):

```
[x <= y | (x,y) <- pairs xs]
```

For the above snippet, it actually is a list of bool values (note that this is surrounded by "[ ]")

What `and` does is it takes in the list of bool values, simply apply the logic of "and" to all the values, then return a bool value.

So, for example, if we supply a list [True, True, True] to `and`, then True will be returned. If any one of the elements in the list is False, then False will be returned.